# Kotlin / Ktor, cant use withtTestApplication because my main is a suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

My main looks like this

```
suspend fun main(testing: Boolean = false) {

    // do some db related stuff with coroutines
    dbSetupRun() // this is using coroutines
    embeddedServer(Netty, 8080) {
       ...
     }.start(wait = true}
```

and my test code looks like

```
  @Test
  suspend fun `test` () {
  
  withTestApplication({ main(testing = true) }) {
            handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "${config.root}/${config.version}/test").apply {
              assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status())
              assertEquals(response, content)

}
```

But I get an error stating `Suspend function 'main' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function` for that code

Quite confused how I am supposed to handle this

Comment: What's withTestApplication?

Comment: It's a Ktor function https://api.ktor.io/0.9.5/io.ktor.server.testing/with-test-application.html that i've been using for testing the application

Comment: Looks like it does not support suspend functions. Why is your main suspend anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your `main` function call into a coroutine builder, like `runBlocking` (which is advised to be used for testing).

`withTestApplication({ runBlocking { main(testing = true) } })`